# How can close jquery popup box on success?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page I have a link. After clicking on this link, it's showing a jquery popup box. html code is below :

```
<input class="modal-state" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" />
   <div class="modal">
     <label class="modal__bg" for="modal-1"></label>
       <div class="modal__inner">
     <label class="modal__close" for="modal-1"></label>    
   <div id="showdoc"></div>    
  </div>
```

This popup box has a **cross (X)** icon to close this popup box. Now I want to close this popup box on the ajax/jquery success method without clicking on the **cross (X)** icon. How can I do this ?

**here is ajax/jquery success method :**

```
success: function (data) {
        $('#result').html('');
        $('#result').show();
        $('#addcontact-img').hide();                            
        getProjectForm(<?php echo $pid; ?>);
        $(".modal__close").dialog( "destroy" );

         $.each( data, function( key, value ) {          
         if(key !== 'error') {
            $('#result').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');              
          }
   });
```

I used `$(".modal__close").dialog( "destroy" );` but it's now working. If i use `$(".modal").fadeOut(500);`, then on success it closes automatically but again it's not open by clicking on the link. I don't know how I can fix it.

Comment: is it a bootstrap modal?

Comment: no it's not. it's simple html.

Comment: if you hide it you must show it when clicking on the link , detect the click on the link and show it for the first time, and when the ajax response is success the hide it with javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have associated dialog `.modal`, You need to use

```
$(".modal").dialog("destroy");
```

Comment: @creativeartbd, Can you show how you are opening dialog? However you can try `$(".modal__close").get(0).click();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".modal").hide();
```

If it's a bootstrap modal, then perhaps this'll work:

```
$(".modal").modal("hide");
```

And to check if your checkbox is checked or not, try this:

```
$(".modal-state").is(":checked") ? $(".modal").hide(): $(".modal").show();
```

Comment: Yes it hiding the popup box on success but if press on the link again then it's not showing the popup.

Comment: You will want to write some code to check if your checkbox is checked or not, and hide/show it based on that. I will put an edit up with an example.

Comment: @creativeartbd I added some code to check the checked status of the checkbox. See if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your code but still not working second time. I mean first time it's hide the box but again If I click on the link it's not showing the popup.